# How to configure Windows Azure Virtual Machines to use as a hosting server to host other websites with standard domain name

Tags: asp.net, azure, hosting

I have purchased Visual Studio Ultimate Subscription . I have also created a brand new virtual Machine, installed IIS Server on it and hosted a couple of website , and they were accessible from localhost. I configured the HTTP endpoint to access it from outside internet. But the url i used to access it was like psdemo.cloudapp.net or the public IP.

I want to start a business of hosting using my azure servers. In that case my problems are:

1) How to access a website hosted on Windows Azure VM using Standard url .. ie. www.domain.com

```
I have registered a domain on bigrock.in . I have googled and it said Edit the CNAME and A records But how in bigrock

and what setting to be implemented on my VM
```

2) I want to install a control panel like Parallels Panel to manage hosting . In that case what setting should i apply to the DNS server.

Please if possible give a full step by step documentation on how to use a Windows Azure Virtual Machine for Hosting Business.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to test that your VM is accessible from the Internet.
You can check this by pinging it.
If this fails check your Firewall in Windows or in your perimeter.

Once you can ping the server you then need to ensure you bindings on your website in IIS are set to the IP address that you have set your DNS records for, or leave that as 'all unassigned'.

Check your DNS records points where you want them to be.

Then continue connectivity test throughout the above.

I would imagine, that either DNS records havent had chance to update, your bindings in IIS are wrong or you haven't configured the firewall to allow port 80 thought.

I don't have an experience using Parralels, I would image It would mean just changing your name servers perhaps ? Would need to seek this elsewhere, though I would imagine that Parallels site would have this data, I was led to believe you could only harness paralels with a *nix webserver and doesn't have same benefits for Microsoft as you can do this in IIS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. IT is working well. Just add 80  endpoints for http. DNS to your cloudapp name. IP as your virtual ip address of your Virtual machine. IIS allows for all unassigned automatically.